# "virtual memory exhausted" when building Docker image

Tags: c++, macos, docker, virtual-memory, docker-build

When building a Docker image, there's some compilations of C++ scripts and I ended up with errors like:

```
src/amun/CMakeFiles/cpumode.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'src/amun/CMakeFiles/cpumode.dir/cpu/decoder/encoder_decoder_state.cpp.o' failed
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
```

But when building the same `.cpp` code on the host machine, it works fine.

---

After some checking, the error message seems to be similar to the one that people get on a Raspberry Pi, https://www.bitpi.co/2015/02/11/how-to-change-raspberry-pis-swapfile-size-on-rasbian/

And after some more googling, this post on the [Mac forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7417584?start=0&tstart=0) says that:

> Swapfiles are dynamically created as needed, until either the disk is
>   full, or the kernel runs out of page table space.   I do not think you
>   can change the page table space limits in the Mac OS X kernel.  I have
>   not seen anything in all the years I've been using OS X.

**Is there a way to increase the swap space for Docker build on Mac OS?**

If not, how else can be done to overcome the "virtual memory exhausted" error when building a Docker image?

Comment: You'll want to clarify which docker implementation you're using on macos.  For example with boot2docker you'll want to adjust the memory granted to the virtualbox vm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That does not seem trivial to do with XHyve.
As stated [in this thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12186986)

> I think the default size of the VM is 16GB. I kept running out of swap space even after bumping the ram on the VM up to 16GB.

Check if the method used for a VirtualBox VM would apply in XHyve: see "[How to increase the swap space available in the boot2docker virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31141359/6309)"

```
boot2docker ssh

export SWAPFILE=/mnt/sda1/swapfile
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=$SWAPFILE bs=1024 count=4194304
sudo mkswap $SWAPFILE
sudo chmod 600 $SWAPFILE
sudo swapon $SWAPFILE

exit
```

Check also this [Digital Ocean Setup](https://github.com/nealfennimore/neal.codes-docker#digital-ocean-setup), again to test in your XHyve context.
[`mkswap` is also seen here](https://github.com/ailispaw/boot2docker-xhyve/blob/master/contrib/makehdd/makehdd.sh#L13) or in [`docker-root-xhyve/contrib/makehdd/makehdd.sh`](https://github.com/ailispaw/docker-root-xhyve/blob/master/contrib/makehdd/makehdd.sh#L11).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have enough available memory in your host, I recommend you to assign more memory to the Docker VM that is behind.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363771/docker-build-from-dockerfile-with-more-memory/45414370#45414370):

> As I can see that you are on OSX, which runs docker over a Linux VM. Configure the max memory clicking the whale icon in the task bar. By default is 2G.

For further information: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#memory

[image]